# Is there a way to know wether my RN Project running on ios emulator or real ios device?

Tags: react-native

In my project,through PushNotificationIOS RN code know device's APNs ID
But emulator has no APNs ID hence RN code can't get it.
It would be helpful if RN code know where it is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the react-native-device-info library:
https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info